# How to get absolute path of a file drag and dropped in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, file, drag-and-drop, filesystems

I am trying to get the absolute path of a drag and drop file using dataTransfer property in event handlers, but not getting the path of the local filesystem.
Here is my html code:

```
<div class="dropzone" appDragAndDrop (fileDropped)="onFileDropped($event)" >
  <input type="file" id="fileDropRef" multiple />
  <h3>Drag and drop file here</h3>
</div>
```

*Here, appDragAndDrop is my custom directive to define listener code*